# How to synchronize processes using semaphores initialized at 1?

Tags: synchronization, signal-processing, wait, semaphore, thread-synchronization

I have a problem synchronizing processes using semaphores that are  initialized at 1.

I have the following example:
There are six processes.
Process 1 can start any time.
Process 2 must wait for process 1 to finish.
Process 3 can start any time.
Process 4 must wait for both process 2 and process 3 to finish.
Process 5 must wait for process 4 to finish.
Process 6 must wait for process 3 to finish.

The semaphores used, must be initialized at 1.

How can we avoid p2,p4,p5, and p6  executing first since all semaphores should be initialized at 1?

Comment: All the processes are created at once and ran simultaneously, and only semaphores initialized to ``1`` should be used, nothing else?

Comment: You are right, there is nothing else.

Comment: Hi Ivan, did you find the solution for your problem?